# LSTM layer in Sequential model requires 3d input but only receives d2

Tags: tensorflow, input, lstm, data-modeling

Data is in 20 batches of 1000 characters with a vocab of 10510 words.
While trying to create an LSTM model to detect ai generated text, my model returns

```
`ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_1' (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "lstm_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received:(None, 10)`


`model = Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=vocab_words, output_dim=10,input_length=1000),
    LSTM(units=1000),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.fit(my_training_batch_generator, epochs=1, batch_size=20)
```

`

```
Model: sequential
```

## Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #

embedding (Embedding)       (None, 1000, 10)          105100

lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 100)               44400

dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 101

=================================================================
Total params: 149601 (584.38 KB)
Trainable params: 149601 (584.38 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)

---

`

I have tried manually telling the LSTM layer to change input_shape=(20,len(tokenizer.word_index)+1) and other variations of this type. I was expecting the error to change but it has not.

Comment: An `LSTM` needs 3d data in the shape of `(batch, time_window, features)`. If you have sentences and each sentence should be a time sequence, try to expand the last dimension, so that you have shape `((20, len(tokenizer.word_index), 1)`.

Comment: I discovered that the problem was my data was formatted incorrectly.